# iOS8 In App Purchase receipt verification

Tags: ios, ios8, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am currently implementing in app purchases for consumables. I have the code up and running, performing purchases and validating the receipt locally.

This is the pseudo code for what I am currently doing:

```
Make purchase request
Respond to paymentQueue updatedTransactions callback
    If Transaction Success
        Validate app receipt fields locally (hash, bundle id, version)
        Validate in app purchase fields (product, qty, transactionid)
        Check transaction has not been seen before
        If Validation passes
            Complete in app purchase and top up user
```

Since SKPaymentTransaction.transactionReceipt has been deprecated in iOS8 I am using the app receipt for verification. I am assuming that it is up to date with the latest consumable in app purchases when the updateTransactions callback is fired.

Is the app receipt allways refreshed before 'paymentQueue updatedTransactions' is called? Is there a chance that it won't be there or it will be stale?

I would hope that the latest receipt data is downloaded with the response. My testing indicates that this is the case but I can't find anything explicitly stating this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no; App receipts may be missing altogether or may be stale and not reflect the latest transactions.

I believe this is why Apple state that you should refresh the App receipt [if validation fails on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2). 'Fails' has a broad definition; it could be any of the validation steps in the aforementioned.

To see that this is the case try the following test script, tested on iOS 8.0.

1. Initiate a purchase, accepting the 'confirm purchase' modal dialog.
2. Before your app's transaction observer is informed of the purchase, kill your app and remove it from the device. A 'thank you for your purchase' dialog should still show.
3. Reinstall your app. When you add your transaction observer, storekit will inform it about the completed transaction.
4. If your App tries to read the app receipt it will find that it is missing.